# Shell Script - Fork A Process

Tags: bash, shell, fork

I've been given a task to make a program show a `menu` like UI and have simple tasks such as `ls` `who` and `top` then make the process of the shell script fork to a child process, then run subsequent commands from the newly created child process. But I don't understand C++ and wanted to use a Shell Script instead. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' 2 #trapping the CTRL + C command so users are forced to use number 4 to stop.
while true #while statement for the return function
do
        clear #clears the screen so it doesn't look messy when looping
        echo "=============================================="
        echo "|        Outside The CPU Shell Script        |"
        echo "=============================================="
        echo "| Enter 1 for Who                            |"
        echo "| Enter 2 for Ls                             |" #basic echos to show the menu
        echo "| Enter 3 for Top                            |"
        echo "| Enter 4 to exit                            |"
        echo "=============================================="
        echo -e "\n" #returns a new line
        echo -e "Enter your selection \c |" #prompts to select while suppressing output
        read answer #reads input and stores value in variable named answer
        case "$answer" in # a case statement (like if/elif statement) using variable answer
                1) who ;; #actual command that is used
                2) ls ;;
                3) top ;;
                4) exit ;;
        esac #ending statement for the case
        echo -e "Enter return to continue \c" #the return statement to bring back to main menu
        read input #read enter and store in variable input
done
```

How would I make the process for when this script is called fork, then control the child process that it creates?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean? Commands like `who` and `ls` just print their output and return, what kind of control do you need?

Comment: If you want to control an interactive program, use `Expect`.

Comment: When you write `ls` in a shell script, the shell forks a child that invokes `ls` and "controls" (really, it just waits for it) the child.  The purpose of doing this exercise in C++ is to understand that process more thoroughly.

Comment: I would like to fork the actual process of the shell script. When doing ps -a the process appears, I’d like to fork that process, then control the child process it makes to further execute commands.